# What is the best TV Tuner in the UK for Vista Media Center or Windows 7 Media Center (64bit)?

Tags: windows-media-center, tuner-card

Looking for dual tuners and whether I can have two dual tuners on FreeView, giving four tuners. My current Hauppauge cards never ran under 64bit Vista... not sure if this has changed or not.

I am looking to order Windows 7 Home Premium and want to ensure that I have the relevant tuners cards also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a [Hauppauge WinTV Nova-TD 500 Dual Digital](http://www.ebuyer.com/product/113946) under Vista64 and I've had absolutely no problems with it - worked pretty much straight out of the box. Haven't tried sticking two cards in though.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the HDHomeRun is the best dual tuner HD tv tuner for Vista Media Center. I am in the US and use the US version but there is a version for European markets that can get free over the air and unencrypted cable channels:

http://www.silicondust.com/products/hdhomerun_dvbt

The one problem is that it will only work with unencrypted channels. It works great with Media Center and is a snap to install.